# Allowing Flash movie to communicate to containing window without exposing full ExternalInterface?

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-3, embed

I'm working on a site that allows administrators to upload arbitrary SWFs and embed them on the page. Administrators are in theory trusted, but I still want to protect against potentially malicious administrators or misguided administrators from harming the site.

A part of the functionality of the site is that the SWFs can communicate to the containing browser page when it's finished and for the page to react.

Now, I can think of two ways to do this:

- Use `ExternalInterface.addCallback` to create a global callback named something like `isComplete` that does logic and returns true or false depending on whether the Flash app is in a completed state. Then, just do something like `setTimeout` to just call that function repeatedly. I don't think this would require me to open up `allowscriptaccess` to the movie.
- Embed the movie with `allowscriptaccess` and have the movie call something like `ExternalInterface.call('done')` when it's finished. This option seems like it requires me to open up `allowscriptaccess`, which is a potential threat since I can't control the SWFs that would be embedded with this directive.

Is there a solution I'm missing that doesn't involve doing the infinite loop and also doesn't require me to open up a security risk?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of embedding your SWFs directly in the main page, embed them in a separate page that's hosted on a subdomain (or some other domain).  Then, display that subpage via an `<iframe>` in your main page.  This way, you'll have a cross-domain `<iframe>`.  Go ahead and give the SWF `allowscriptaccess` permissions.  Then, communicate via `postMessage` (or a cross-browser simulation script) with the iframe. This way, the SWF can do anything they want to the page, but there's only one controlled "tunnel" to the main page.

Comment: Thanks! This seems promising. I'll have a shot at implementing it to see how it works. It feels like a pain having to spread it across multiple domains, but it's worth exploring.

Comment: Depending on your DNS and `httpd.conf` settings, you may be able to reference a page via a subdomain that's not specifically configured.  E.g. reference `http://www.mydomain.com/somewhere.html` via `http://fake.mydomain.com/somewhere.html`.